# security group aws specific ip http/https blocks everything

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, firewall

I've follow the documentation of I've read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

and I want to create a security group in AWS which allows only one IP access to ports 80 or 443, but AWS is blocking everything even the IP which should have access when I apply this group.

We are using nginx in the ec2 server and the certificate was created with certbot

[image: my inbound rules]

Comment: It is possible that your problem is related to using Public IP addresses vs Private IP addresses, but that is difficult to tell since you have provided very little information. Can you tell us more about your setup? For example, what is the resource that is being protected by the security group (EC2 instance? Load Balancer?), and what is the resource that is being permitted access (another resource in the same VPC, or something on the Internet)? How are the two resources connecting -- is it via a public IP, private IP or a DNS name? Please Edit your question to add the extra details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm using a ec2 instance and I am trying to connect via public IP with the URL of the server from my machine

Comment: Does it work if you temporarily open the rule to `0.0.0.0/0`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it works with 0.0.0.0/0,  I'm using cloudflare maybe this is the problem

Comment: Are you saying that CloudFlare sits in front of the EC2 instance? Then, yes, the requests will not be coming "from" your computer, so they would be rejected.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Do you know if it's possible to allow throw Cloudflare an specific IP (origin)

Comment: Did a web search, found this: [Configuring IP Access Rules – Cloudflare Help Center](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967-Configuring-IP-Access-Rules). Mind you, it doesn't make a lot of sense putting Cloudflare in front of a service if it is only accessed by one person.

Comment: if you want to use an SSL certificate you need the domain, so you need it. the final target is to get this server only accessible from a VPN

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "blocking everything"?

From these 2 rules, port 80 and port 443 are only open to the one IP that you had given. If this is a webapp, it is likely that you'll have a loadbalancer setup to receive the traffic.

- Check the ELB security group and block traffic there (If there is an ELB setup)
- Check the VPC NACL if there are any block for port 80/443 traffic. If that is the case, NACL rule will take precedence here
- Make sure you check your outbound rules also. If by "Blocking everything", you meant the outbound traffic

Comment: I meant blocking everithing even the ip which should allow to have access. I’ve edited the description with this info. Really weird behaviour which does not allow me access with the ip rule settled

Answer (score 0):

Edit the inbound rule to be only lock out any other port to the instance ip address only, while you open 443 and 80 to everyone.
eg. if ur ec2 instance public ip is 13.255.77.8 and you don't want port 5000 to be accessible to the public, create a custom tcp with your that is only acessible to that port ie mapping port 5000 to this ip - 13.255.77.8/32